# Relationship between html and js tabs in codepen when showing code for sample react project?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am going through this tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

A link is provided in this tutorial to codepen where the code already exists.

An option to using codepen is to write and run the code locally. At no point in the tutorial are you instructed to write html code. My question is, is the html code "generated" from the js code? Where does this html come from? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CodePen handles the linking between JS, HTML, and CSS for you, so you don't have to include boilerplate such as `script`, `style`, `head`, `body`, and so on in your HTML.

If you want to see the actual underlying code, right click on an element within the display area and click "Inspect". Everything sandboxed within the parent `iframe` of that element is your HTML.

Comment: so the html is what is generated from javascript? no human has written the html although the css and of course the javascript/react code were written by humans -- i guess the html is actually generated from both the javascript and the css?

Comment: You say, "so you don't have to include ... and so on in your HTML" -- but central to the question is that I don't think I wrote HTML at all -- can you do reactjs without writing HTML? If sometimes you must write HTML, when is it necessary?

Comment: React needs at least an HTML "skeleton" with a root element to run. Assuming you're using React with Babel (configured in CodePen settings), the automated process is something like this: 1) Create HTML boilerplate 2) Transpile React JSX code to plain JavaScript 3) Inject the result of #2 into boilerplate 4) Transpile SCSS (if used) to CSS 5) Inject CSS. Not necessarily in that order.

Comment: Thanks -- I do see now that an index.html was created I think.